# "make test" fails because of syntax error

Tags: python, osx-yosemite, openlayers-3

I am trying to setup a development environment for ol3 on Os X Yosemite. Following [these](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) instructions, I passed "make test" successfully and have installed the necessary Python modules. The next step "make check" fails. Here is the output:

```
Running gjslint...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/gjslint", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('closure-linter==2.3.13', 'console_scripts', 'gjslint')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2302, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/closure_linter/gjslint.py", line 168
    print '%s: %d' % (path, len(path_errors))
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
make: *** [build/timestamps/gjslint-timestamp] Error 1
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the answers, the error is due to the fact that I am using the wrong version python. The required version is 2 and not 3. I have now checked "python -V" and it shows that my python version is 2.7.10. Why does "make check" still use the 3.4 version?

Comment: the code is python2, but you are running it under python 3

Comment: Can I expect it to work properly if a manually replace "print" by the print-function in the python-script-files?

Comment: Problem Solved: I had to place /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin into my path before /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin